# File replication between 2 Windows servers

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup, replication

I currently have 2 dedicated servers, both running Windows Server 2003.

The first server is being used as a web server simply to handle large file uploads, averaging about 130 files per day each at around 100MB in size.

The second server is there as a backup server in case anything goes wrong with the first one.

I need some software to perform file replication. Each file that's uploaded to server 1 needs to be replicated over to the backup server, right at the time of upload.

I haven't got bucket loads of cash to spend unfortunately so I'm looking for a cheap & reliable option.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Robocopy is free -- so is DFS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run robocopy with the monitor option. This would detect any new files on server 1 and copy them to server 2.

[The Job and Monitoring Options of RoboCopy](https://serverfault.com/questions/55733/the-job-and-monitoring-options-of-robocopy)

Answer (score 3):

Would [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_%28Microsoft%29) be an option?

Comment: If it's 2003 R2 I'd definitely go with DFS. If it's not R2 I'd go with  a robocopy-based solution. I would rather trim my toenails with a turbocharged chainsaw than have to deal with the NTFRS replication engine again.

Comment: Stock 2003 DFS ain't that bad either, but if it was Win2K I'd definitely join you in the queue for that chainsaw.

Comment: I'd agree w/ mh-- RTM W2K3 NTFRS and DFS isn't horrible, though DFS-R is definitely worlds better.